# Use wget to crawl specific URLs

Tags: regex, web-crawler, wget

I am trying to crawl links from a website then use download manager to download files.

I've tried:

`wget --wait=20 --limit-rate=20K -r -p -U Mozilla "www.mywebsite.com"`

I can't figure out how to use `wget` or regular expressions to save the desired links only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wget offers a wide variety of options for fine tuning files download in a recursive crawl.

Here are a few options that can interest you:

- `--accept-regex urlregex`

Download any url matching *`urlregex`*. *`urlregex`* is a regular expression which is matched against the complete URL.

- `--reject-regex urlregex`

Ignore any url matching *`urlregex`*. *`urlregex`* is a regular expression which is matched against the complete URL.

- `-L`

Tells wget to follow only the relative links.

Relative links example:

```
<a href="foo.gif">
<a href="foo/bar.gif">
<a href="../foo/bar.gif">
```

Non relative links:

```
<a href="/foo.gif">
<a href="/foo/bar.gif">
<a href="http://www.server.com/foo/bar.gif">
```

#### References

- [Wget : Recursive Accept/Reject Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options)
- [Wget : Following Links](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Following-Links)